# Contents of textView change when contents are selectable

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, screen-rotation

I am currently working on a project which requires me to dynamically add textView objects to a LinearLayout based on the contents of an array.

```
chapter = Home.chapters.get(index);
    layout.removeAllViews();
    String dataText = chapter.content;
    String[] dataArray = dataText.split("~");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        String paragraph = dataArray[i];
        String outputParagraph = paragraph.replace("`", "\n");
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ttc_text, null);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(outputParagraph);

        //tv.setTextIsSelectable(true);

        layout.addView(view);

    }

    TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleView.setText("Chapter " + chapter.title);

    layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getBaseContext()) {

        public void onSwipeRight() {
            retreatBackward();
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            advanceForward();
        }
    });
```

I have configured saveOnItemStateChanged in order to restore the correct contents of the textViews when the screen is rotated.

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        index = savedInstanceState.getInt("Chapter");
    }

 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Chapter", index);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

However, whenever the screen is rotated, the textViews present within the parent layout do not display their original contents. Instead, the same number of textViews in the original layout all display identical contents, that is, the contents of the final textView added to the layout.

This issue only presents when the text within the TextViews is designated as selectable, either through the `setTextIsSelectable()` function or through the XML markup. As such, the selectability of the text must be somewhat impacting the way in which the contents of the TextViews are repopulated after a rotation, although I cannot seem to establish exactly why. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: why you are not using a table layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is due to your device's configuration change. When you rotate your device a configuration change event occur. Add the following code to your **Manifest.xml** and your **activity** class. Hope, that will solve your problem.

**Changes to Manifest.xml file**  --->  (Suppose XYZ is your activity class)

```
 <activity android:name=".activities.XYZ"
              android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

**Add this to your XYZ activity class  --->**

```
  @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  }
```

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

1st

super.onSavedInstanceState(...) should be the first thing called.  Your 'save' stuff should come after.

2nd

You will most likely need to save all of the textviews, so you can repopulate them, or save the array and repopulate based on that.

I found this site to be very good for explaining the ins and out of save-instance-state handling.

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/